# Access elements of json in an Array in jquery

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to access an data inside an Array in Jquery but I am unable to do so. The data is getting received in success function in Ajax. My array looks like this:

```
[{"id":"22","name":"Ignis","color":"white","manufacturer":"Suzuki","manufacturing_year":"2017"}]
```

I am trying to access it like:

```
var obj = data;
var name = obj[0].name;
alert(name);
```

its getting me undefined but When I store the same received value in store it in variable like below it gives me result:

```
var mydata = [{"id":"22","name":"Ignis","color":"white","manufacturer":"Suzuki","manufacturing_year":"2017"}];
var obj = mydata;
var name = obj[0].name;
alert(name);
```

I need every value of the json to be stored in variables named after there respective keys. 
Please let me know how can I handle this data.
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you _unable to do so_? What have you tried?

Comment: Why when you already have simple access using the property keys? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @vikesh you can get a clue from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49606162/how-to-get-dynamic-key-and-value-from-json-using-jquery

Comment: @vikesh could you change your question and write your expected result?

Comment: What you're trying to do makes absolutely no sense, and there is 100% a better way to do it. Try to create [a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that explains what (code) brought you into the situation.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question. Do suggest if you have a solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're asking for something like this

```
var  mydata='[{"id":"22","name":"Ignis","color":"white","manufacturer":"Suzuki","manufacturing_year":"2017"} ]';
var mydataobj= JSON.parse(mydata);
var name= mydataobj[0].name;
var id= mydataobj[0].id;
var color=mydata[0].color;
```

It goes same for all other values

Comment: I have used JSON.parse(data); then tried to access the variable but it still giving me undefined.

Comment: Yeah I did that too. It gives me this error:   json_decode is not defined

Comment: @vikesh I guess this updated answer will solve problem