# How to access elements of an array of JSON in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to fetch an array of JSON objects onto my react page. Now, the array I get is :

`[{"_id":"5c4309fb643589310818165e","TableTime":"10:30- 11:00","TableType":"Pool Table 1","TableStatus":"Booked"}, 
{"_id":"5c430a3f2f788e322d2430d0","TableTime":"10:30- 11:00","TableType":"Pool Table 1","TableStatus":"Booked"}]`

I first set it in a state variable `result` in `componentDidMount()` method.
In `render` method, when I do :

```
    const { result } = this.state;
    var slot = result;    
    console.log(slot);
```

I get the array as above. But when I do :

```
    const { result } = this.state;
    var slot = result;    
    console.log(slot[0].TableTime);
```

I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'TableTime' of undefined`

I searched for it and tried this link and used `JSON.parse()`: [Access elements of json in an Array in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49721693/access-elements-of-json-in-an-array-in-jquery)

But then it gave me the error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`

The relevant code is as follows :

```
 class Timeslots extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
  super(props, context);
  this.state = {
    result: [] 
 }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getList();
  }

  getList = () => {

    fetch("/purchase")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(result => this.setState({ result }))
  }


  render() { 
    const { result } = this.state;
    var slot = result;    
    console.log(slot);
   );
  }
 }

 export default Timeslots;
```

I just want a way so that I can access the `slot[0].TableTime` and use it?

Comment: The `render` method runs even before the result has been fetched. At that time the value of `result` is just a blank array. That is why you are getting the error. All you have to do is to add a `if(result[0])` condition in render method which checks if value is there then only use that.

Comment: @PrakashSharma thanks a lot! It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the component renders. Then you get results from fetch . So you should have a null check in your render .
Something like return result !== null ? console.log(result):null

Also the slot variable is not required.